# how to load a laravel view page in a popup box

Tags: jquery, laravel, popup, laravel-5

i want to load update/delete view inside popup box of my laravel 5 app. currently i have put a link to open it in a separate window. please advice me

this is my link
list.blade.php

```
   <td><a href="{{url('user-edit',$user->id)}}">Update</a></td>
```

this is the form i want to load

update.blade.php

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ action('Admin\UserController@update', ['id' => $user->id]) }}">

        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Full Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input  type="text" class="form-control" name="full_name" value="{{ $user->full_name }}">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Username</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input  type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="{{ $user->username }}">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input  type="text" class="form-control" name="password" value="{{ $user->password }}">
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                    Register
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
    <div class="col-md-6 text-right">

        {!! Form::open([
        'method' => 'DELETE',
        'route' => ['destroy', $user->id]
        ]) !!}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">
            Delete
        </button>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
    </div>
```

Comment: What is the question? Does popup mean same page or new window?

Comment: @charlietfl same page .. what i want is in my user list page i put anchor tag for each row for update reocrd . i want to load that form insde popup box same page

Comment: Thre are many many choices available in web search for `modal` or `dialog` and using ajax content in them is very common. Do some searching. Questions like this asking for recommendations on how to do something are off topic here

Comment: @charlietfl i tried this <a  href="{{url('user-edit',$user->id)}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#register-modal">Update</a>

Comment: but its not working.. please advice @charlietfl

Comment: you need to make ajax call to get the content. Suggest you study some ajax tutorials